# Azure Web Job logs

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-queues

I want to check my WebJob app.
I am sending a queue message to 'blobsaddressqueueu' queue.

After few seconds the message disappears from the queue - means that it triggered the WebJob app.
Then I see the message in 'blobsaddressqueueu-poison' - means that something went wrong in the process.

When I go to Log Stream (after I turn it on) under ParseMatanDataWebJob20170214032408, I do not see any changes and the only message I get in Log Stream is 'No new trace in the past 1 min(s)' and so on.

What am I doing wrong?

All I want to do is check the csv file (the queue message directs the webJob to the blob container with the csv file), and check the process when the csv file is read by WebJob so I will figure out why it goes to poison.

Comment: A simple `Console.WriteLine` will do the trick to log in webjobs.Put some `try/catch` block and try to log with `console.writeLine`

Comment: When you test it locally, any other messages can you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not see any changes and the only message I get in Log Stream is
>   'No new trace in the past 1 min(s)' and so on.

Maybe you could change your Logging Level in diagnostics logs, and if your level is right and you could not see the logs you could go to `D:\home\LogFiles\SiteExtensions\Kudu` in Kudu to check the detailed log file.

For you I suggest checking the running logs, you could get it in portal like the pic shows.Also you could get the log file in Kudu at `data/jobs/continuous/jobName`.
[image]

You still could add trace message logging in a WebJob, about the details you could refer to this [article](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2017/03/06/adding-trace-message-logging-in-azure-webjobs/).

If you still have other questions, please me know.

Comment: Thank you, I actually do have other question, I posted it here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54021998/azure-web-jobs-suddenly-stopped-working-properly 

Thanks